# Issue in Dynamic relative layout

Tags: android, dynamic, android-relativelayout

Kindly check this one.

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
    item.setImageResource( R.drawable.invite );
    item.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    item.setLayoutParams(params);
    item.setId( mIconIdCounter );
    layout.addView(item, params);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item.getId());

    TextView tv1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv1.setText("Invite");
    tv1.setTextSize(15);
    tv1.setId(2);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item.getId());
    layout.addView(tv1, params);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, item.getId());

    ImageView item2 = new ImageView(this);
    item2.setImageResource( R.drawable.logout );
    item2.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    item2.setLayoutParams(params);
    item2.setId(3);
    layout.addView(item2, params);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item2.getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, item.getId());
    TextView tv2=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv2.setText("Logout");
    tv2.setTextSize(15);
    tv2.setId(4);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item2.getId());
    layout.addView(tv2, params);


    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    ImageView item3 = new ImageView(this);
    item3.setImageResource( R.drawable.fbplaceholder);
    item3.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    item3.setLayoutParams(params);
    item3.setId(5);
    layout.addView(item3, params);
```

Here , i have to set item3 Imageview in the above of item imageview. But m unable to do it.
In this code item3 is overlapping item.
i have to set it in the top of item imageview. 
Kindly suggest me where m going wrong.

Thanks in advance
Gaurav Gupta

Answer (score 0):

as you adding the item in the last and it is relative layout where item overlaps as per params

try this

add item3 as first element

and

in item params add this params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item3.getId());